# Appium:I hv 2 class, ClassA & ClassB.I am executing these 2 class using testng.xml file.I want to know dat for ClassB do I need to put @Beforeclass?

Tags: java, c#, selenium-webdriver, appium

Class1:

```
public class LaunchApp {

    AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void Test1() throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capability.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");
        capability.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capability.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1.1");
        capability.setCapability("deviceName", "Samsung Galaxy On5");
        capability.setCapability("app",
                "D:\\whatsapp.apk");
        capability.setCapability("PackageName",
                "com.movocado.socialbostonsports");
        capability.setCapability("ActivityName",
                "com.movocado.socialbostonsports.Activity.LogInSceen");

        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(
                    "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capability);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
```

Class2:

```
public class DrawerMenuTest {
    AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void DrawerMenuIcon() {

        WebElement drawerMenu = driver.findElement(By
                .id("com.movocado.socialbostonsports:id/rel_drawer"));
        try {
            drawerMenu.click();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Problem:
Second class is showing `NullPointerException`. Suggest me a solution.

Comment: In you second class you didn't instantiate `AndroidDriver`...that is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing `AndroidDriver` into `LaunchApp` but does not pass this driver reference into `DrawerMenuTest` where you are creating only refrence variable of `AndroidDriver` with `null` that's causes of `NullPointerException`.

To overcome it you should create separate `singlton` class which will give single instance of `AndroidDriver` to each and every class as below :-

```
public class DriverInit {

    private AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;

    private static DriverInit driverInit = null;

    public static DriverInit getInstance() {
        if (driverInit == null) {
            driverInit = new DriverInit();
        }
        return driverInit;
    }

    private DriverInit() {
         DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();

         capability.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");
         capability.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
         capability.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1.1");
         capability.setCapability("deviceName", "Samsung Galaxy On5");
         capability.setCapability("app", "D:\\whatsapp.apk");
         capability.setCapability("PackageName",  "com.movocado.socialbostonsports");
         capability.setCapability("ActivityName", "com.movocado.socialbostonsports.Activity.LogInSceen");


         this.driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(
                "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capability);

         this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return this.driver;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this into `LaunchApp` class as below :-

```
public class LaunchApp {

        AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;

        @BeforeTest
        public void Test1() throws MalformedURLException {
            driver = DriverInit.getInstance().getDriver();
            //now do your stuff with this driver
        }
  }
```

And use in `DrawerMenuTest` class as below :-

```
public class DrawerMenuTest {
    AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void DrawerMenuIcon() {
        //get driver instance first
        driver = DriverInit.getInstance().getDriver();

        WebElement drawerMenu = driver.findElement(By
                .id("com.movocado.socialbostonsports:id/rel_drawer"));
        try {
            drawerMenu.click();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Hope it helps..:)